# Run select on click

Tags: javascript, select, click

**Hi all!**

I need to make some changes on select click, but I can catch it.

**This is what I have: html**

```
<div class="col-xs-2" name="field_value">
    <a name="select_edit" href="#">
        <select name="fields[value][]" class="form-control">
            <option value="zzz">zzz</option>
        </select>
    </a>
    <button data_input_button="input_value_button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary hidden">
</div>
```

When someone click on select I need to press button.

Now I am listening a on click, but it works only on double click.

**js:**

```
$('[name=field_value]').click(function(e) {
    alert(1);
});
```

How I can fix it, that it start to work with click not with change.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use onchange?

Comment: And one thing, I think your code works, see here http://jsfiddle.net/cu0xLbvj/

Comment: 1) I need double click, open and close select

Comment: 2) At the begining no values on select, and I need to fill it, with openin popup

Comment: I dont know what he need,Will you please specify what you want to do with this java script.or what is the real purpose?@  user2264941

Comment: I think you bette use onchange event

Comment: I have select, when user click on it - opening popup where user can fill it, or remove existing options.

Comment: With on change it works, but with double click, I just need to make it works with on click.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 <select name="fields[value][]" class="form-control" id="mySelect"   onselect="callFunction()">
         <option value="zzz">zzz</option>
    </select>
```

js:

```
function callFunction(){
  alert("this is an alert");
}
```

Comment: @user2264941 try now, I forgot to add () in the function

Comment: Yes, I know this, but it works on change. I need on click.

Comment: select doesnt have onClick event

Comment: what do you need exactly? @user2264941

Comment: I have select, when user click on it - opening popup where user can fill it, or remove existing options.
     
With on change it works, but with double click, I just need to make it works with on click.

Comment: create a div outside the select <div onClick="callFunction();"> select and all </div>